# jQuery CSV plugin won't split rows into arrays-of-arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, html-table

I am trying to use the jQuery "CSV" plugin, as documented here: http://code.google.com/p/js-tables/wiki/CSV

According to the documentation:

```
// Convert CSV data into array of arrays
jQuery.csv()("1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n"); // = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
```

But when I attempt to do something similar, it just seems to treat the "\n" as another character in the middle of an array element.

What am I doing wrong? 
I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and Firefox 3.5.10 for testing. I have also tried it with jQuery 1.3 and get the same result.

If it is a problem with the plugin, then can someone suggest another plugin for reading CSV?
My ultimate goal is to convert CSV from a string into an HTML table; the only plugin I can find that specifically does this requires the CSV to come from a file, which is not desirable for my task.

Here is a minimal test page I put together which illustrates that it's not separating the lines into sub-arrays:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSVtest</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var lines = $.csv()("a,b\nc,d");
      alert(lines[0][1]); // Displays: b 
                          //           c instead of the expected b
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you're using double and not single quotes, which don't do a good job of acknowledging newlines.

Comment: @Steven Xu, that's not true of JavaScript strings.  Aside from the obvious, there's no difference between `"` and `'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're using the [latest version](http://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) of the plugin.  I copied and pasted your example using jQuery 1.4.2 and the (now outdated) CSV plugin from <s>http://js-tables.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.csv.min.js</s> and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/KRzzF/

Tested in IE8, IE6, Google Chrome and Firefox.  I also tested

```
alert(lines[1][1]);
```

and sure enough, the alert displayed "d".

Comment: Aha.. Dumb old me, I trusted that the first google match would be the latest version.  Downloading the newer version from your link seemed to solve it.

Comment: Ahem. The latest version of jquery.csv.min.js is @ http://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv. I would know, I'm the author of jquery-csv. (:

Comment: @Evan: awesome, I've updated the answer to reflect the current location.

Comment: I just realized, even though the file name is the same it was using a different parser. Your answer uses jquery-csv but the API calls of the library in op's question. The call should be `$.csv.toArrays()`

Answer (score 1):

If you only deal with simple data (no quotation) you can do something like this:

```
function csv(text) {
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  for ( var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ ) {
    if (!lines[i])
      lines.splice(i, 1);
    else 
      lines[i] = lines[i].split(",");
  }
  return lines;
}
```

Comment: I could write the parsing code myself, but I don't have control over the incoming stream of data; there could be embedded commas within quotes, embedded quotes within quotes, or other standard CSV things that I would prefer not to have to re-invent.